# "Cannot use variable of type []struct as []interface" while spreading

Tags: go, slice

**Prototype function**

```golang
func test(i ...interface{}) {
    // Code here
}
```

**Intended use**

```golang
type foo struct {
    // Fields
}

foos := []foo{
    // foo1, foo2 ...
}

test(foos...) // ERROR
test(foos[1], foos[2], ...) // OK
```

**Error**

> cannot use foos (variable of type []foos) as []interface{} value in argument to test

## Description

The intended use is to be used like the built-in function `append()`.

https://golang.google.cn/pkg/builtin/#append

```
func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type
```

Although, as I've seen `append()` doesn't use `interface{}`, which is strange, since anywhere that I searched all people say to use `interface{}` when you don't know the type. But they don't.
Nope, `append()` uses a "build-in" type called `Type`, which apparently the docs say that it's a `int`. Although, I cannot use it. There isn't such type. And neither I would know how to use it if there was.

https://golang.google.cn/pkg/builtin/#Type

```
type Type int
```

So, I'm very confused here.

## Questions

1. Why does the spread operator not work as intended? For example, in Javascript the spread operator just spreads the array into items. But in Golang it seems like it **keeps the same array parameter type** as it is but gives the compiler later an instruction to spread it. Which is odd.
2. Are we even able to make similar custom mechanisms like `append()` at all? Or am I a dummy and I'm using something wrong anyway?

Comment: `append` has built-in function super powers.

Comment: The builtin package documentation uses `Type` as a placeholder for any type.  This use of `Type` is not valid Go syntax and is not useable in application defined functions.  As peterSO says, append has super powers.

Comment: I see. I feel like that is a bit unfair to be honest. Thanks for clearing this out. So my question is still valid. Why and who gave the downvote? It's a legit question that will surely help other people too and I made it as crystal clear as possible. I dont know what stackoverflow wants anymore.

Comment: A future version of Go may give you the power of `append` and other builtins.  See https://blog.golang.org/why-generics.

Comment: @CeriseLimón If you would feel like it, you could form an answer since I think you provide all the information there is to answer the question. I'll mark it as solved when possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that this is the issue that you are running into here.

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice

I am not an expert in this but have hit this before, the "slice of empty interface" is not an interface and therefore cannot be replaced by any type which is the issue that you are having, it has to do with the memory structure being different. The above has a far better explanation than one that I can give.

Comment: I see. Looking it up again, I can see that `...interface{}` is interpreted as `[]interface{}`. I just thought this shouldn't be the case. Because the intention with the spreading operator is not to say "I want an array of interfaces", but to say "I want a set of interface{} elements". That's why I thought this was strange & confusing, especially when coming from a JS Background :3. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You can typecast your typed slice to get what you need:

```golang
generic := make([]interface{}, 0)
for _, f := range foos {
  generic = append(generic, f)
}
test(generic...)  // works
```

Comment: You could `generic := make([]interface{}, len(foos))`, `for i, f := range foos`, and `generic[i] = f`, since the length of `foos` is known. Looks like this is linked to in the other answer: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice#what-can-i-do-instead

Answer (score 1):

Combining the two non-negative answers into what I feel is the best solution:

```golang
interfaceSlice := make([]interface{}, len(foos))
for i, v := range foos {
    interfaceSlice[i] = v
}
test(interfaceSlice...)
```

Partially inspired by:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice#what-can-i-do-instead